# IOS UIAutomation - how to get elements when I create ios UIAutomation JS script

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I have a new project need create auto test script with ios application, but only can provide ipa file (developer build), cannot provide source code. Currently I used Tuneup JS. I have some questions need help. Please see details as below.

1. I only have ipa file no source code, so how to get application elements and how to locate element? Is there any documents can reference? If can provide some examples should better.
2. If this ios application is HTML5 application, can automate?
3. When I use Tuneup JS to create script is there any recommended IDE to help create script? Because very hard to remember all APIs.

very very appreciate for your helps.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.logElementTree();` and in the instruments window, when you run the app, it will log the elements of the current window. 
check out apple's documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/Introduction/Introduction.html

Your second question makes no sense.

I use sublime text editor to write my tests, although it isn't an IDE, just a fancy text editor.